# Save scroll position of input datalist on page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html

This `<div>` contains a `input` field, and the `input` has a `datalist` containing variables from a SQL database.

```html
echo'<div class="form-group h7 text-left mt-2">
    <div class="text-dark">
            <input runat="server" class="form-control text-left" style="width: 250px;" list="versions" id="versionId" name="Version" onchange="this.form.submit()" autocomplete="off" placeholder="'.$VersionPlaceH.'" value="">
            <datalist id="versions">';
            foreach ($VersionList as $key) {
                echo'<option value="'.$key['Version'].'">';
            }
            echo'
            </datalist>
    </div>
</div>';
```

On the php page this looks like this, and as you can see there is a large scroll bar, on the dropdown.

[image]

When a item from the list is choosen, a auto-submit is called `onchange="this.form.submit()"`, and when the page reload it could be nice to have saved the scroll position when the user clicks on the input field again.

How can this scroll position be saved?

**EDIT**

Tried to make a test useing `<div>`, but  for some reason it doesn't work?

```js
const lastItem = localStorage.getItem('lastItem');
if (lastItem) {
    const itemElement = document.getElementById(lastItem);
    if (itemElement) {
        itemElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
let options = {
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 1.0
}
const target = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-item');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
        console.log(entry.target);
        localStorage.setItem('lastItem', entry.target.id);
    })
}, options);

target.forEach(item => {
    observer.observe(item);

});
```

```html
<div id="scrollable-list" style="height: 100px; overflow:auto;">
  <div id="Test1" class="scroll-item">Test1</div>  
  <div id="Test2" class="scroll-item">Test2</div>  
  <div id="Test3" class="scroll-item">Test3</div>  
  <div id="Test4" class="scroll-item">Test4</div>  
  <div id="Test5" class="scroll-item">Test5</div>  
  <div id="Test6" class="scroll-item">Test6</div>  
  <div id="Test7" class="scroll-item">Test7</div>  
  <div id="Test8" class="scroll-item">Test8</div>     
  <div id="Test9" class="scroll-item">Test9</div>  
  <div id="Test10" class="scroll-item">Test10</div>  
  <div id="Test11" class="scroll-item">Test11</div>  
  <div id="Test12" class="scroll-item">Test12</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt that’s possible. This control gets rendered by the browser.

Comment: Is the user supposed to be able to enter any random text they like into that field, or are they supposed to choose from the given values only? If the latter, this should be a `select` field in the first place. (And then you can set the _selected_ option upfront.)

Comment: @CBroe They  should be able to enter the text themselves, the datalist is to help them

Comment: Then I don’t think what you want is directly possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#customizing_datalist_styles: _“The style of the list produced by a <datalist> element is platform-dependent, so if you want to customize the display of the options, you have to implement your own custom solution that overrides the default behavior.”_

Comment: @CBroe so I might have  to make my own `<div>...</div>`  with some javascript, so I can save the element i reached in the div or something like that?

Comment: @CBroe Since I know the datalist element the user choose, can I somehow make it automatically scroll down to that element in the list, if it's there?

Comment: The example on the mentioned MDN page applies custom CSS to the `datalist` element, you could try something similar (add a max-height and overflow), and then try if setting the scroll position “the usual way” (`scrollTop`) works …

Comment: @CBroe Tried to make something, but can't seem to make it work? Can you see any problems with it

Comment: Hard to tell, especially because localStorage access does not work here in the sandboxed snippet. The principle of getting a specific element scrolled into view using that method itself works though, see https://jsfiddle.net/58g7brx4/

Comment: @CBroe That helped me alot thanks! I think I have a solution now